# create GS1-128 with Zxing

Tags: zxing

I'm using Zxing to attempt to generate a GS1 Code 128, more specifically a USPS tracking number. Zxing doesn't support GS1, but it does support Code 128. I'm trying to add the FNC chars myself as so:

```
private static final char FNC1 = (char) 29;
barcodeValue = MessageFormat.format("{0}420{1}{2}{3}", FNC1, toZip5, FNC1, trackingNumber);
BarcodeFormat code128Format = BarcodeFormat.CODE_128;
Code128Writer code128Writer = new Code128Writer();
code128Writer.encode(barcodeValue, code128Format, width, height);
```

This does produce the following barcode:
[image]

But when I attempt to read this image (using https://products.aspose.app/barcode/recognize#/recognized), I'm getting back the following:

[image]

It's just a Code128, and not a GS1. I've used this tool with other GS1 Code128 barcodes, so I'm pretty sure the tool is good.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Please try another value for the FNC1 character.
FNC1 = '\u00f1';
The Code128 writer doesn't use the value 29 like other writers.